# Does template copy constructor override default copy constructor?

Tags: c++11

I would expect that the existence (or absence) of the line with **the default copy-constructor** in the following example should make some difference, but the behavior (on Windows) is the same in both cases:

```
template <class T>
struct Vec {
    T x = T();
    T y = T();

    Vec() = default;

    Vec(const Vec&) = default;   // default copy ctor

    template <class Other>
    Vec(const Other &o)          // templated copy ctor
      : x(o.x), y(o.y) 
    {
        cout << "templated copy ctor";
    }
};

Vec<int> i;
Vec<double> d = i;     // calls templated 'copy ctor'
Vec<double> dd = dd;   // does not call templated copy ctor, whether 'default copy ctor' exists, or not !
```

It seems that the compiler always generates a default constructor (that is if I do not explicitly `delete` it, or make it `protected`), and therefore the **templated copy ctor** never matches.

If the compiler always generates a default constructor, why would I ever want to write this line?
Why not always omit it instead?

```
Vec(const Vec&) = default;   // default copy ctor
```

What would be a wise coding standard ?

- to always type the default copy ctor, or
- to always omit typing the default copy ctor?

Comment: Only `Vec(const Vec&)` is an actual copy-constructor. The template constructor is a *conversion* constructor (which allows implicit conversion from any other type).

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that the compiler always generates a default constructor (that is if I do not explicitly delete it, or make it protected), and therefore the templated copy ctor never matches.

Yes: the copy constructor isn't template so is a best match for a `Vec const &`.

As Some programmer dude observed in a comment, the template one isn't (to be exact) a copy-constructor.

> If the compiler always generates a default constructor, why would I ever want to write this line?

Not always.

The rules regarding deleted/defaulted constructors and deleted/defaulted assignment operators are complicated so, for example, the copy-constructor is implicitly deleted when there is a user declared move constructor or a user declared move assignment.

In that case, a `= default` can re-enable the default copy constructor.